# Why is the KL Divergence between contracted $Bin(N,\theta)$ and $Bernoulli(\lambda)$ convex function in $\lambda$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, machine-learning, information-theory

I need to prove that the the KL Divergence $D(\bar{\mu}(\theta)||Y(\lambda))$ between the following variables is convex w.r.t $\lambda$.

The variables are defined as:
$ \bar{\mu}(\theta) =\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} X_{j}(\theta)$ where $X_{j}(\theta)\sim Bern(\theta)$ for all $j$,
and $Y(\lambda)\sim Bern(\lambda)$.

I was hoping there is a closed expression that I could prove convex by derivating w.r.t $\lambda$ twice and show that it is positive.

In fact - I have read online that the KL divergence is convex w.r.t its arguments when the arguments are probability distributions, but in my case I want to show convexity w.r.t the parameter $\lambda$ that controls the distribution on the right.
Maybe the two cases are the same? I would love an explanation.

Comment: Your $Y$ and $S_N$ have different sample space. How is your KL divergence even defined in this case. I suspect you have a typo somewhere. To see KL divergence is convex in $\lambda$ alone is not hard. Let $p(z(y))$ be some random variable $Z=Z(y)$'s density. Then $D(Z|Y)=\int\log(p(z(y))/q(y))p(z(y))dy$, where $q(y)=\lambda^y(1-\lambda)^{(1-y)}$. It suffices to focus on $-\int dy \log(q(y))p(z(y))$. That is obviously convex in $\lambda$. In fact, that expression is linear in $\lambda$ as $p(z(y))$ depends upon $\theta$ only. If your $Y$ is sum of Bernoulli r.v., the result is similar.

Comment: You are right, I edited it. Both variables now get values between [0,1].
Regarding you explanation - I am not sure why it suffices to focus only on part of the expression? And why convexity of this term implies convexity of the whole KL divergence?